# get device token inside -(BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I don't know how to get device token (APN) inside

```
- (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

the only place I can get the device token in AppDelegate is in

```
- (void)application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
```

where application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will run asynchronous or after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. So, is there any way to get device token in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?? Because I want to pass it into my ViewController that pushed from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Here is my sample code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    for (id key in launchOptions) {
        NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value %@", key, [launchOptions objectForKey: key]);
    }
    AddViewController *avc = [[AddViewController alloc] init];
    avc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    avc.pushToken = self.pushToken;
    UINavigationController *uinav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init ];

    [uinav pushViewController:avc animated:YES];
    [_window addSubview:uinav.view];
    [avc release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
    self.pushToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is your one and only chance to get the current device token. However, you can store the result in `NSUserDefaults` and read it from there on launch. Most of the time, if the app hasn't been uninstalled/reinstalled, the device token remains the same between launches.